# German umlaut binary representations

Tags: unicode, filenames

I have a strange problem where two Unicode variables that I am trying to compare look the same but they are different in binary representations. When I look at the uploaded file it shows up with a slightly different binary representations of the filename. This happens on uploads from Safari browser only. I am no expert in Unicode I am puzzled by two strings that have different binary Unicode representation but are the same.

Does any body has insight why this is? What is the extra -byte to represent German umlaut actually means?

```
     apple-macintosh:~ vijay$ hexdump /tmp/a
     0000000 55 6e 74 65 72 73 74 c3 bc 74 7a 74 65 5f 50 72
     0000010 6f 6a 65 6b 74 65 2e 64 6f 63 78               
     000001b
     apple-macintosh:~ vijay$ more /tmp/a
     Unterstützte_Projekte.docx
     apple-macintosh:~ vijay$ hexdump /tmp/b
     0000000 55 6e 74 65 72 73 74 75 cc 88 74 7a 74 65 5f 50
     0000010 72 6f 6a 65 6b 74 65 2e 64 6f 63 78            
     000001c
     apple-macintosh:~ vijay$ more /tmp/b
     Unterstützte_Projekte.docx
     apple-macintosh:~ vijay$
```

The byte sequence 0xc3bc (umlaut) is represented as 75cc88. I am not sure if these are distinct representation of umlaut. Any insight would be very helpful for me to see how I can compare these filenames in a reliable way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C3 BC` is the UTF-8-encoded form of the single Unicode code point `ü`.

`75 CC 88` is the UTF-8-encoded form of the two Unicode code points `u` and `̈`.

The second is the decomposed form with an ASCII `u` and a combining mark.

Some programming languages have libraries to deal with this, such as Python:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> s = 'Unterstützte_Projekte.docx'
>>> s1 = ud.normalize('NFC',s) # Combined form
>>> s2 = ud.normalize('NFD',s) # Decomposed form
>>> s1 == s2                   # They don't compare equal
False
>>> print(s1)                  # But look the same...
Unterstützte_Projekte.docx
>>> print(s2)
Unterstützte_Projekte.docx
```

Convert two values to the same from to compare

```
>>> ud.normalize('NFC',s1) == ud.normalize('NFC',s2)
True
>>> ud.normalize('NFD',s1) == ud.normalize('NFD',s2)
True
```

For reference see [Unicode.org's](https://unicode.org/) [Unicode Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).